# Why does this JavaScript code ignore the timeout?

Tags: javascript

Question:

Consider the below JavaScript code, which works fine so far, except...
... that it completely ignores the timeout.

Why ?

I tested it with sleeping 10s in the ashx handler (timeout is set to 5s), and so far it never complained about timeout. I will increase the timeout for production use, of course.

```
function createXMLHttpRequest() 
{
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
    return null;
}


function ExecuteSQL(strParameter1, strParameter2, strParameter3) 
{
    try 
    {
        strParameter1 = encodeURIComponent(strParameter1);
        strParameter2 = encodeURIComponent(strParameter2);
        strParameter3 = encodeURIComponent(strParameter3);

        var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();

        var dtNow = new Date();
        var dt = Date.parse(dtNow) + dtNow.getMilliseconds()

        var params = "prm1=" + strParameter1 + "&prm2=" + strParameter2 + "&prm3=" + strParameter3 + "&prm4=END";


        params = params + "&NoCache=" + dt;

        //var URLget = "cgi-bin/RequestData.ashx?NoCache=" + dt + "&param1=value1&param2=value2";
        var URLpost = "cgi-bin/RequestData.ashx?NoCache=" + dt;
        xhReq.open("POST", URLpost, false);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        /*
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
        */
        var MAXIMUM_WAITING_TIME = 5000;

        var requestTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            xhReq.abort();
            alert("Request cancelled. \nReason: Timeout (" + MAXIMUM_WAITING_TIME/1000 + "s) exceeded.");

            // Handle timeout situation, e.g. Retry or inform user.
        }, MAXIMUM_WAITING_TIME);
        xhReq.send(params);

        if (xhReq.status != 200) {
            clearTimeout(requestTimer);

            if (xhReq.status == 400) 
            {
                var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
                alert(unescape(serverResponse));
            }
            else
                alert("XMLHttpRequest Error\nHTTP Status: " + xhReq.status + "\nStatusText: " + xhReq.statusText);
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(requestTimer);
            // Handle error, e.g. Dis
            var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
            alert("Successfully return from execution.");
            //alert(unescape(serverResponse));
        }

    } catch (ex) {
        alert("Error in JavaScript-function \"ExecuteSQL\".\nError description: " + ex.Description);
    }
} // End Sub ExecuteSQL
```

Comment: is that "'" on the var URLget line really in the code? or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to delete everything that has nothing to do with the timer and see if your problem becomes *incredibly obvious*.

```
function something() 
{
        var requestTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            alert("something");
        }, 1);

        if (something) {
            clearTimeout(requestTimer);
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(requestTimer);
        } 
}
```

Comment: except that there is a xhReq.send(params); statement afer requestTimer, so I don't see what's obvious here....

Comment: I didn't even notice that he was trying to make a *synchronous* call.  I don't think a timer will even fire during a synchronous call, which is among the top fifteen reasons not to make them.

Answer (score 0):

define this variable  **var requestTimer** outside **function ExecuteSQL**

Comment: Why? I don't see what difference that would make.

Comment: Why do people keep voting this up?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a synchronous call using XMLHTTPRequest. Try making it async by changing false to true in the following call:

```
xhReq.open("POST", URLpost, true);
```

Currently, due to your sync call the timeout gets cancelled.

Comment: The problem is stripped down in this example. I need a sync call, else I'm going to run into trouble elsewhere (3rd party vendor, unchangable), that's why I don't use JQuery.

Comment: I am getting the timeout alert, please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H9CsB/1/. I get the timeout if is use an invalid domain URL. If I change the URLPost value to point to localhost then I dont get the timeout alert.