# How do you set a session variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can this be done with a PageMethods call?  I need to save some variables in a control so that they can be used by a control on another page at a later time. Is there a way to do this via JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like a cookie? or are you after the `localStorage/sessionStorage` objects?

Comment: Yes a cookie or a session value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie), [localStorage, or sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem() and sessionStorage.getItem() work great!

Answer (score 3):

You can use JS to change the values in a hidden field, and capture them on the postback, which personally I think preferable to cookie usage if the value is only needed for the life of the current session.

Comment: I can't use a hidden field because it would only be visible on control A when I need to access it on control B.

Comment: I think you did not understand my answer.  You use the hidden value ONLY to relay the value back to the server, at which time you capture it and store it in a session variable which can later be used in any other context on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to do this with PageMethods.

You can add a generic handler (*.ashx) and then do a XMLhttpRequest to this URL, passing it parameters.

Note that the ashx handler needs to inherit from IRequiresSessionState, in order to access a session.

You can also get a session value that way.

Like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler , IRequiresSessionState
{
   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
   {
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

      string item = context.Request.QueryString["item"] ?? "";
      string update = context.Request.QueryString["update"] ?? "";

      switch (item)
      {
         case "A":

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(update))
               context.Session["A"] = update

            object a = context.Session["A"];   
            context.Response.Write(a != null ? (string) a : "none");

            break;

         case "B":

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(update))
               context.Session["B"] = update

            object b = context.Session["B"];
            context.Response.Write(b != null ? (string) b : "none");

            break;
      }
   }

   public bool IsReusable 
   {
      get { return false; }
   }
}
```

See my post here for XMLhttpRequest:
[Why does this JavaScript code ignore the timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621319/why-does-this-javascript-code-ignore-the-timeout)

You might want to add a parameter no_cache=TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS, in order to beat browser caching.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it the following way:

javascript:

```
function SendData(data) {
    var postbackarg = "@@@@@" + data;
    __doPostBack("txtTest", postbackarg);
}
```

VB In Page_Load event:

```
If Me.IsPostBack Then
    Dim controlName As String = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
    Dim args As String = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")
    ProcessUserInterfaceData(controlName, args)
    If (controlName = "txtTest" AndAlso args.IndexOf("@@@@@") = 0) Then
        args = args.Substring(5, args.Length - 5)
        'args now = data from the UI
    End If
End If
```

This started from an example I found somewhere else. I cannot find it.. The only purpose for the 5 '@' is to identify the postback as coming from SendData.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables cannot be set using `Javascript` directly
But you can use the following code to set session variables in aspx page

```
<%Session["SESSION VARIABLE NAME"] ="SOME STRING"; %>
```

You can check the same variable using an alert in javascript

```
 alert('<%=Session["SESSION VARIABLE NAME"] %>');
```

*Yes session variable can be set using Pagemethods using the below way*

declare the below code in aspx.cs page

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static void functionname(string st)
        {
            Home h = new Home();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionUserName"] = st;
            h.strUserName = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionUserName"];
        }
```

and call the function using pagemethod in aspx

```
 PageMethods.functionname("HELLO");
```

*this will set the session variable to HELLO*

You can also make an ajax call to the webmethod if you dont want to use pagemethods.function!!